# Create a command which allows us to return to the beginning of the line

Tags: line-breaking

With the following codes

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,graphicx,amsthm,mathtools,systeme}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-tab,moreverb} % tableau de signe moreverb not needed
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{pifont} %bouni
\usepackage{fancybox} %pour faire l'encadrement
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages} %pour inserer une page pdf
%---- Dimensions des marges ---
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm}
%----New Structure Exercice -----
\newtheoremstyle{sboxexc}% name of the style to be used
  {\topsep}% measure of space to leave above the theorem. E.g.: 3pt
  {\topsep}% measure of space to leave below the theorem. E.g.: 3pt
  {\itshape}% name of font to use in the body of the theorem
  {0pt}%  of space to indent
  {\bfseries}% name of head font
  {}% punctuation between head and body
  { }% space after theorem head; " " = normal interword space
  {\thmname{#1}}% Manually specify head
\newcounter{counter}
\setcounter{counter}{1}
\theoremstyle{sboxexc}
\newcommand{\optionaltext}{}
\newtheorem*{Exc}{\shadowbox{ Exercice \arabic{counter}\optionaltext}\\}
\newcommand{\exo}[2][]{\renewcommand{\optionaltext}{#2}\begin{Exc}\normalfont}
\newcommand{\finexo}{\renewcommand{\optionaltext}{}\end{Exc}\addtocounter{counter}{1}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Définition}
%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{definition}
cccccc
\end{definition}
Now,...
\begin{definition}
\begin{itemize}
\item [(1)] cccccc
\end{itemize}
\end{definition}
Now,...
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%debut exercice%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\exo{}
aaaaaa
\finexo
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% fin exercice%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Now,...
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%debut exercice%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\exo{}
\begin{itemize}
\item [(1)] aaaaaa
\end{itemize}
\finexo
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% fin exercice%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

> I want to create a command entitled for example `\sauteligne` which ullows me when I want to return to a new line. That when I want to return to a new line I just write `\begin{definition}\sauteligne \begin{itemize} \item [(1)] cccccc \end{itemize} \end{definition}` and `\exo{}\sauteligne \begin{itemize} \item [(1)] aaaaaa \end{itemize} \finexo`. Then I will get

[image]

Comment: Theorem structures are one item lists, so your macro could just call `\item`

Comment: `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} % not needed in new latex versions`  note this is misleading, the comment would be true for the utf8 option, but if your file is latin1 then that line is still needed. Note however any code on this site is always utf-8 so accented letters in documents copied back from here will not work if you leave in that line.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm using an old version and when I replace `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` by `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` it does not work

Comment: so your files are in latin1 so you need that line, and the comment is wrong as you need the line. But when you post the code here the site converts it all to utf-8 so as posted here the whole line is wrong as it specifies latin1 so will stop the document working.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks Professor. I have deleted it. I will greatful if you can help me in my question. Thanks a lot.

Comment: yes I was just looking at at that, the intended usage as documented by amsthm is to use `\newline` in the last but one argument, but somewhere your other code is stopping that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

by hand you can always do `\mbox{}` before the list, this drops that in automatically

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
% code copied from stackexchage is never latin-1 \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} % not needed in new latex versions
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,graphicx,amsthm,mathtools,systeme}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-tab,moreverb} % tableau de signe moreverb not needed
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{pifont} %bouni
\usepackage{fancybox} %pour faire l'encadrement
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages} %pour inserer une page pdf
%---- Dimensions des marges ---
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm}
%----New Structure Exercice -----
\newtheoremstyle{sboxexc}% name of the style to be used
  {\topsep}% measure of space to leave above the theorem. E.g.: 3pt
  {\topsep}% measure of space to leave below the theorem. E.g.: 3pt
  {\itshape}% name of font to use in the body of the theorem
  {0pt}%  of space to indent
  {\bfseries}% name of head font
  { }% punctuation between head and body
  { }% space after theorem head; " " = normal interword space
  {\thmname{#1}\par}% Manually specify head
\newcounter{counter}
\setcounter{counter}{1}
\theoremstyle{sboxexc}
\newcommand{\optionaltext}{}
\newtheorem*{Exc}{\shadowbox{ Exercice \arabic{counter}\optionaltext}}
\newcommand{\exo}[2][]{\renewcommand{\optionaltext}{#2}\begin{Exc}\normalfont\mbox{}\par}
\newcommand{\finexo}{\renewcommand{\optionaltext}{}\end{Exc}\addtocounter{counter}{1}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definitionz}{Définition}
\newenvironment{definition}[1][]{\definitionz[]\mbox{}\par}{\enddefinitionz}
%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{definition}
cccccc
\end{definition}
Now,...
\begin{definition}
\begin{itemize}
\item [(1)] cccccc
\end{itemize}
\end{definition}
Now,...
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%debut exercice%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\exo{}
aaaaaa
\finexo
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% fin exercice%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Now,...
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%debut exercice%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\exo{}
\begin{itemize}
\item [(1)] aaaaaa
\end{itemize}
\finexo
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% fin exercice%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```